# How do I fix problem with 'script.js' not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically one of my scripts work but the other one doesn't. I am trying to customize the play button functions with javascript but whenever I try to load the script it seems like the script has no effect on the video.

I have checked the code itself and even went back to the index.html to see if I made any errors with the tags. I also found out after inspecting the script is not there but it's declared in the index.html.

```
 index.html





    <div class="container">


    <div class="c-video">
                        <video class="video" src="stranding.mp4"></video>
                        <div class="controls">
                                <div class="orange-bar"></div>
                                    <div class="orange-juice"></div>

                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="play-pause"></button></div>

                   </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <script src="alert.js"></script>



________________________________________________________________________
        var video = document.querySelector("video");
        var juice = document.querySelector("orange-juice");
        var btn = document.getElementById("play-pause");




        function togglePlayPause() {
            if(video.paused){
                btn.className = "pause";
                video.play();

         } else {

            btn.className = "play";
            video.pause();
         } 
        }

        btn.onclick = funtion() {
            togglePlayPause();
        };


    ________________________________________________________
    stye.css 

    .buttons button.play:before {
        content: "\fo4b";
    }

    .buttons button.pause:before {
        content: "\f04c";
    }

    .orange-bar{
        height: 10px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .orange-juice{
        height: 10px;
        background-color: silver;
    }
```

I want the script to cause the video to play/pause but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you adding the script to your index.html with the correct path? did you try to add the script inside the index.html file enclosed in  **<script> /*your code*/</script>** tags?

Comment: I did the <script>/my code/ </script> technique.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly taking the reference of the Play/Pause button.
Instead of:

```
document.getElementById(".play-pause");
```

use

```
document.getElementById("play-pause");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "`.`" class selector in `document.getElementsById`

```
var btn = document.getElementById(".play-pause");
```

Without seeing the HTML and knowing exactly what is going on, try

```
var btn = document.getElementById("play-pause");
```